# Subquery returning more than one value per row

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a subquery that returns multiple rows which is what I need. But I'm getting the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    number, 
    req.dv_cat_item, 
    req.dv_stage, 
    req.dv_state req_state, 
    u.dv_u_lob, 
    u.dv_location,
    req.opened_at,
    req.closed_at, 
    req.dv_closed_by,
    (SELECT name FROM sc_item_option vars
     OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(vars.value, ',') s
     LEFT JOIN cmdb_ci_server AS c ON c.sys_id =s.value
     JOIN sc_item_option_mtom mtom ON vars.sys_id = mtom.sc_item_option
     JOIN sc_req_item req ON mtom.request_item = req.sys_id 
     WHERE mtom.request_item = req.sys_id 
       AND item_option_new = '915ec43a13ff520012c73482e144b002') --as [Server]
FROM 
    sc_req_item req
JOIN 
    sys_user u ON u.sys_id = req.u_requested_for
               AND req.dv_cat_item = 'system id request' 
               AND req.sys_id IN ('a0880b7c1bb1c41c5c68b8061a4bcb99', '6a066d111bb14cd0fafc1f861a4bcb2b')
```

I've tried using where exists and I've tried moving that subquery down below those last 4 lines. No luck so far.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want the multiple rows to be represented?

Comment: You have the table, and alias, `sc_req_item AS req` in both your outer query and your sub-query. Is it your intention to be correlating the sub-query to the outer query? When you say that you need the sub-query to return multiple results, it seems that either you need to correlate it, or you want duplicated rows. Which would be correct?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Hi Gordon, I would like to have multiple rows/duplicated rows

Comment: @EricBrandt, I'd like to have the other columns duplicated in another row. I'm new to SQL so I'm not sure what correlation is in this context. I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, yoiu have to make sure that the subquery returns one value.
If it returns more than one sql won't know which one to choose as a result
I beleive this is what you should do:

```
SELECT number
    ,req.dv_cat_item
    ,req.dv_stage
    ,req.dv_state req_state
    ,u.dv_u_lob
    ,u.dv_location
    ,req.opened_at
    ,req.closed_at
    ,req.dv_closed_by
    ,b.name
FROM sc_req_item req
JOIN sys_user u ON u.sys_id = req.u_requested_for
    AND req.dv_cat_item = 'system id request'
    AND req.sys_id IN (
        'a0880b7c1bb1c41c5c68b8061a4bcb99'
        ,'6a066d111bb14cd0fafc1f861a4bcb2b'
        )
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name
        ,request_item
    FROM sc_item_option vars
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(vars.value, ',') s
    LEFT JOIN cmdb_ci_server AS c ON c.sys_id = s.value
    JOIN sc_item_option_mtom mtom ON vars.sys_id = mtom.sc_item_option
    JOIN sc_req_item req ON mtom.request_item = req.sys_id
    WHERE item_option_new = '915ec43a13ff520012c73482e144b002'
    ) b ON b.request_item = req.sys_id
```

Comment: this returns an error and b.reuquest_iem is underlined red. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chrissy, I corrected the code. missed request_item after name in the subquery. Let me know if it works now